# Real-time 3D Scene-reconstruction into Physics Engine

Tags: unity, 3d, unreal, physics-engine, bullet-physics

I am trying to create a game where the user scans the room using RGBD camera and reconstructs 3D scene. This scene would be integrated into physics engine, after an object recognition algorithm tells it what objects are there in the scene and of what shape and size. Finally, after being rendered in Physics Engine, user should be able to interact with the environment. 
I know how to do 3D scene reconstruction from images, I can figure out how to contruct objects and interact with them in Physics Engine. I know how to do object recognition, shape and size. 
However, I am not sure **how to integrate the output of 3D scene reconstruction, Object Recognition as input to the physics engine**. 
Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Anytime you're tempted to ask "is it possible", you should always stop to ask yourself "what specifically am I worried would make this *im*possible? This will often lead you to a more constructive question, with answers more interesting than "yes/no". What particular barrier have you encountered so far when trying to process your RBGD data into physics representations? The more precisely you articulate the issue, the better we can help you find solutions/workarounds/alternatives.

Comment: I would like to take a RGBD camera, and convert the image to a 3D point cloud and use the depth info, point cloud and image to reconstruct 3D scene of the current room and update this environment into physics engine running in real time. This will allow to take the current surrounding and make them interactive in the physics engine. I can pause the live input from images, drop a cup in the physics engine.

Comment: The purpose is to make the current environment intractable (as per the laws of physic). Does my explanation help? I can elaborate more.